# What does does the z-index value 'unset' do?

Tags: css, z-index

According to the [MDN docs on z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), one possible z-index value is 'unset'.

```
/* Global values */
z-index: inherit;
z-index: initial;
z-index: unset;         /* <-------- */
```

What does using that value do?

Comment: My mistake. I should have seen that this was global; i.e. it can be applied to anything. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset. Unlike `initial` and `inherit`, I had never seen it before and thought it was a z-index thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unset is a global value. It is not just a value for z-index.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset):

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it
>   inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. In other
>   words, it behaves like the inherit keyword in the first case, and like
>   the initial keyword in the second case. It can be applied to any CSS
>   property.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-unset-value) may help. Basically, the z-index from an element's parent is inherited or initialized (set to default of `auto`)